# When using NewTX, let picture's \circle produce “o” instead of “a” in the text layer of PDF

Tags: pdftex, circles, newtxmath, newtx, picture-mode

Running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\opencolon}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \put(1.7,1.7){\circle{3.4}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\circle{3.4}}
    \end{picture}}%
}
\begin{document}
\opencolon% or \(\opencolon\); it doesn't matter
\end{document}
```

visually produces the open colon ⦂ while putting `a a` into the text layer of the PDF.  However, visually, a circle is more similar to the letter “o” rather than to the letter “a”.  For the purpose of the textual search in PDF viewers such as `evince` and converters such as `pdftotext`, why not making the circle an “o” instead of an “a”?  To reach this goal, how to change the `picture` environment or the `\circle` command?

(While I am extremely well aware of the possibilities provided by {Xe|Lua}(La)TeX, this very question is extremely specific to pdflatex and NewTX fonts; please keep the comments and answers clean from unrelated stuff.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the ActualText to use for copying from the PDF

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\opencolon}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \put(1.7,1.7){\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=o}\circle{3.4}\EndAccSupp{}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=o}\circle{3.4}\EndAccSupp{}}
    \end{picture}}%
}
\begin{document}
\opencolon% or \(\opencolon\); it doesn't matter
\end{document}
```

Or if in fact you want a colon as the actual text choose variant b or c

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\opencolon}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \put(1.7,1.7){\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=o}\circle{3.4}\EndAccSupp{}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=o}\circle{3.4}\EndAccSupp{}}
    \end{picture}}%
}
\newcommand{\opencolonb}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \BeginAccSupp{ActualText=:}\begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \put(1.7,1.7){\circle{3.4}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\circle{3.4}}
    \end{picture}\EndAccSupp{}}%
}

\newcommand{\opencolonc}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2982}\begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \put(1.7,1.7){\circle{3.4}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\circle{3.4}}
    \end{picture}\EndAccSupp{}}%
}
\begin{document}
\opencolon

\opencolonb

\opencolonc
\end{document}
```

If I cut all the text from this document and paste as plain text I get

```
oo
:
⦂
```

Comment: Thx! Ideally, I'd prefer 
`\newcommand{\opencolon}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \BeginAccSupp{ActualText=⦂}
      \put(1.7,1.7){\circle{3.4}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\circle{3.4}}
      \EndAccSupp{}
    \end{picture}}%
}`
but it doesn't compile :-(. Would 
`\newcommand{\opencolon}{%
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{.1ex}%
    \begin{picture}(3.4,10)(0,0)
      \BeginAccSupp{ActualText=:}
      \put(1.7,1.7){\circle{3.4}}
      \put(1.7,8.3){\circle{3.4}}
      \EndAccSupp{}
    \end{picture}}%
}`
present any issues?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I did wonder if you wanted : as the actual text but you asked for o so that's what you got:-) you could use ⦂ but you probably need one of the additional options to configure the encoding also you would want the beginappsup around the whole picture not just around the \put

Comment: Earlier, I did not even dream of having : or  ⦂ . Thanks for letting me know!!!

Comment: @GeekestGeek extended answer

Comment: Enormous thanks! I'd give you a double checkmark if I could.